# Is there a way to see what files have been added or changed after a certain time/date?

Tags: linux

A person will be changing some files on my server soon. I don't 100% trust this person, but I have no choice on the matter.

Is there a way in Linux to do either/both of the following?

a) See what files were changed after a certain time/date.

b) See what changes were made.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: for case 'a', you can use 'find -ctime -mtime'. Generally, you can enable audit to watch the changes: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

Comment: In case you have plenty of disk space available, why not do a full copy of the system in question to another location inaccessible for the other party? Later you could run `rsync --dry-run` against the directory tree saved previously and see what files have changed (and in case you have to, run `diff` against those you're interested in).

Comment: Don't you want to know _what the person does_?